# How can I make "go get" get transitive dependencies?

Tags: go

I have a go project in github at [github.com/usmanismail/gpns](https://github.com/usmanismail/gpns) which people can pull in using:

```
go get github.com/usmanismail/gpns
```

However, my project depends on a few other projects such as goconfig. How can I setup my project such that when people go get my project they will also get the required dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go get` already gets all the dependencies:

> Get downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies.

If you need more control consider vendoring your dependencies using a tool like [godep](https://github.com/kr/godep).

Comment: I am seeing a counter-example in that `go get` is not downloading the sub-dependencies for `golang.org/x/net/html/charset` and thus my project is not compiling.

Answer (score 1):

To update all dependencies including transitive:

```
go get -u
go get -u all
go mod tidy
```

The first one updates the direct dependencies, the second one does the transitive ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about test-dependencies, instead of `go get`, you could try `go get -t github.com/usmanismail/gpns`

If you are talking about binary dependencies, tools etc, I think you will have to tell the users that this is a requirement or provide a script that installs the dependencies automatically.

ref. https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies